# Creating Generic templates from DTOs c#

Tags: c#, scaffolding

I have a class that has multiple classes being set. I want to run [something] against the class file and generate my own custom files based on the list of classes. Since my code base will use the same naming convention all over the system. What tools are available that would allow me to generate custom templates from DTO data such as the below? I will be happy to write the code to generate my templates, I need to know what tools allow me to do this type of dynamic templating from files inside a project. I am already using typelite to do some of this generation for my front end but it doesn't allow the creation of typescript files based on templates. It only creates d.ts files for contract static typing.

**DTO Example**

```
public class SomeClass {

[DataContract]
public FirstNameClass firstname {get; set;}

[DataContract]
public LastNameClass lastname {get; set;}

[DataContract]
public GenderClass gender {get; set;}

}
```

**Edit #1**

I have found the following which are not generic enough to allow me to create formatted HTML

http://cjlpowers.github.io/TypeScripter/

https://github.com/ToTypeScriptD/ToTypeScriptD

http://nswag.org/

**Edit 2**

The [DataContract] Attribute describes my JSON shape which is created via Reflection. This part is taken care of.

**JSON Example**

```
{
SomeClass {
    firstname: {
        HasValue: true,
        Value: "Name",
    },
    lastname: {
        HasValue: false,
        Value: "",
    },
    gender: {
        [Male: {}, Female: {},]
    },
  }
}
```

I need to generate HTML/TS scripts like the below, be aware for the sake of not giving out a long line of html / ts the below will be much larger, the DTO has a lot more properties, and I have a lot of logic that will need to be created around each scenario. I would like to create custom C# code that parses the DTO Example and create the below HTML. The type script side is angularjs and for each "SomeClass" I have I want to generate separate components for them.

```
<input value="$ctrl.jsonView.firstname">
<input value="$ctrl.jsonView.lastname">
<input type="radio" value="$ctrl.jsonView.gender">

@component{ 
jsonView = $serviceCall(getJsonForPerson());
}
```

I need to read "FirstNameClass|firstname", "LastNameClass|lastname", "GenderClass|gender" in memory and iterate over each one of them creating/editing 2 files, someClass.component.ts and someClass.component.html.

Comment: What do you want to generate? What would a "custom file" or "generic template" look like, based on the DTO shown above? Have you found out about T4 templates or Roslyn?

Comment: The DTO is passed to my UI as JSON. I want generate the html and typescript files on the fly. It seems that T4 templates can not (with out my knowledge) parse .cs files to generate code. I will take a look at Roslyn.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include example input and output. How do you send a _class_ as JSON?

Comment: @CodeCaster The subject matter isn't the JSON. It's the DTO. I want to parse the parent class for all classes being set under the [DataContract]. I then want to create files (HTML/TS) that match those properties.

Comment: Look, I know plenty about code generation, JSON parsing, inspecting type metadata, using Roslyn to parse C# and whatnot, so I would consider myself more than qualified to attempt to answer this question, but it's simply unclear to me what your input and desired output look like. You show a class. What do you want to do with that class? How? When? Why? What have JSON and HTML got to do with all this? Why do you have a `[DataContract]` attribute, which is only applicable to types, applied to properties?

Comment: @CodeCaster please see Edit 2